# How to access a generic property in a template?

Tags: templates, generics, macros, properties, umbraco7

I'm vaguely familiar with mvc/C# and I'm trying to Umbraco to setup a template page. I'm trying to define a macro in a template file so it is editable. I cannot get a straight answer to how to do this. The setup is basically like this.

I have a template, it has generic properties which are to be editable. I have an xslt which is setup as a macro. My issue is when I add the macro to the template, I cannot define the parameters for the macro to the generic properties setup on the template.

mediaFile is the name of the item and its alias.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "umbLayout.cshtml";
}


@Umbraco.RenderMacro("InsertWidgit", new {mediaFile=[some param]})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. When you have a template and want to get access to a generic property in a document type you can access it like this.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
     Layout = "umbLayout.cshtml";
 }


@Umbraco.RenderMacro("InsertWidgit", new {mediaFile=@CurrentPage.mediaFile})
```